# Strange beahviour. `read` works when issuing commands, but not inside a function

Tags: function, julia

I am just trying to restart with Julia (made some tries a couple of years ago but the libraries were still missing too much stuff).

I am now trying something really simple and can't figure out why doesn't work.

If I run these very same commands directly outside a function, I get what I want, but if I put them inside a function, I get an error when calling the `read` command inside my `read_datafile` function:

```
using ArgParse, ZipFile, CSV, DataFrames

function read_datafile(fp)
    z = ZipFile.Reader(fp)
    a = z.files[1]
    df = DataFrame(CSV.File(read(a)))
    
    return df
end

read_datafile("./folder1/test.zip")
```

> SystemError: seek: Bad file descriptor
>
> Stacktrace:  [1] #systemerror#48 at ./error.jl:167 [inlined]  [2]
> systemerror at ./error.jl:167 [inlined]  [3] seek at ./iostream.jl:129
> [inlined]  [4] read(::ZipFile.ReadableFile, ::Int64) at
> /home/morgado/.julia/packages/ZipFile/fdYkP/src/ZipFile.jl:508  [5]
> read at /home/morgado/.julia/packages/ZipFile/fdYkP/src/ZipFile.jl:504
> [inlined]  [6] read_datafile(::String) at ./In[14]:4  [7] top-level
> scope at In[15]:1

EDIT:
Added more info.

`using Pkg; Pkg.status()`

```
Status `~/.julia/environments/v1.5/Project.toml`
  [c7e460c6] ArgParse v1.1.1
  [336ed68f] CSV v0.8.3
  [a93c6f00] DataFrames v0.21.8
  [92fee26a] GZip v0.5.1
  [7073ff75] IJulia v1.23.1
  [6f49c342] RCall v0.13.10
  [fd094767] Suppressor v0.2.0
  [70df011a] TableReader v0.4.0
  [a5390f91] ZipFile v0.9.3
```

Comment: I am not seeing the same errors you seem to be getting. Can you post the versions of the packages you are using by sharing the output of `using Pkg; Pkg.status()`?

Comment: @PaSTE Sure, just added that. This is indeed a strange behaviour, and occurs both in a Jupyter notebook or by calling a file from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, it's a 5 year old unsolved bug in the ZipFile package :( : https://github.com/fhs/ZipFile.jl/issues/14

Need to write the function with a **global** variable:

```
function read_datafile(fp)
    global z = ZipFile.Reader(fp)
    a = z.files[1]
    df = DataFrame(CSV.File(read(a)))
    
    return df
end
```